# RabbitMQ list queue only for specific queue via Command line

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, command-line-interface, amqp

I would like to know if its possible to `list the message_unacknowledged of specific queue` ? I mean I have a 4-5 queue in 1 vhosts but I want to check the `message_unacknowledged` for specific queue only.

Here is my command:

```
C:\Python26\python.exe C:\Python26\rabbitmqadmin.exe --host %host% --port 443 --ssl --user %user% --password %password% list queues messages_unacknowledged
```

Output:
[Output of with name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z91YQ.png)

Here is what I want to see only.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr1wB.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you run this command

```
C:\Python26\python.exe C:\Python26\rabbitmqadmin.exe help subcommands
```

It will show all the commands that you can run.
Unfortunately you cannot get the count of messages for a specific queue.

But you can write a script to hit this url which will return a Json with all the details about the queue

```
http://username:password@queue-server:15672/api/queues/%2f/queue_name
```